# Rows as columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot

My table, `t`, has the following format:

[image]

I would like to transform this table into:

[image]

The `COUNT_XXXXX` columns are determined by counting the number of rows where `CLICKSKEY` is not NULL organised by `SUBJECT_TYPE`.  The `COUNT_CLICKED` column counts the number of rows where `CLICKSKEY` is not NULL independent of `SUBJECT_TYPE`.

Could anybody help?

Comment: And your date data goes where?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement and return a value every time the condition is true. In the end you just have to sum those values.

```
SELECT
  DEALER_ID, 
  SUM(CASE SUBJECT_TYPE WHEN 'Marketing' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_MARKETING, 
  SUM(CASE SUBJECT_TYPE WHEN 'Random' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_RANDOM, 
  SUM(CASE SUBJECT_TYPE WHEN 'Alert' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_ALERT,
  COUNT(*) AS COUNT_CLICKED 
FROM t 
WHERE CLICKSKEY IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY DEALER_ID;
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, each of your CASEs is returning a value regardless of whether the condition is true or false: when it's true, the CASE is returning 1, otherwise 0. Both 1 and 0 are values.

Comment: Good point. One can think about to omit the ELSE Statement, because the 0 is not needed, but this could lead into a _Case not found for CASE statement_ error.

Comment: In MySQL there's a [CASE *statement*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) and a [CASE *operator*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case). Absence of ELSE can be a problem only for a CASE statement, and what you have here is a CASE operator. If you omit ELSE in a CASE operator, then `ELSE NULL` is implied. Still, in your situation it's better to have `ELSE 0`, so that, when no row matches the condition, a 0 is returned instead of a null.

Comment: To make it clear, in my first comment I had an issue only with your terminology and not with your solution, which makes perfect sense to me.